# Maven building for GoogleAppEngine, forced to include JDO libraries?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-2, jpa, jdo, datanucleus

I'm trying to build my application for GoogleAppEngine using maven. I've added the following to my pom which should "enhance" my classes after building, as suggested on the [DataNucleus documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/enhancer.html)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

According to the documentation on GoogleAppEngine, you have the choice to use JDO or JPA, I've chosen to use JPA since I have used it in the past. When I try to build my project (before I upload to GAE) using `mvn clean package` I get the following output

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-ec

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.jdo -DartifactId=jdo2-api -Dversion=2.3-ec -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.jdo -DartifactId=jdo2-api -Dversion=2.3-ec -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:maven-plugin:1.1.4
    2) javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-ec

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:maven-plugin:1.1.4

from the specified remote repositories:
  __jpp_repo__ (file:///usr/share/maven2/repository),
  DN_M2_Repo (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Apr 03 16:02:39 BST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/258M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas why I should get such an error? I've searched through my entire source code and I'm not referencing JDO anywhere, so unless the app engine libraries require it, I'm not sure why I get this message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The DataNucleus Maven plugin requires the JDO2 API JAR (even for JPA) as documented [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/guides/jpa/tutorial.html#step6) and as reported in the trace:

```
  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:maven-plugin:1.1.4
    2) javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-ec
```

The odd part is that [`jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar`](http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/javax/jdo/jdo2-api/2.3-ec/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar) **is** in the DataNucleus Maven repository (that **is** declared in the [POM](http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/org/datanucleus/maven-datanucleus-plugin/1.1.4/maven-datanucleus-plugin-1.1.4.pom) of the plugin) and Maven **has** checked this repository as we can see in the trace.

**Update:** Ok, this **is** definitely weird and I don't know why the build is failing exactly (maybe a problem with dependencies ranges). As a workaround, declare the JDO2 API JAR as dependency in the plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-ec</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>        
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>

</project>
```

With this dependency declared, the JAR gets downloaded.

Comment: That'll teach me to skip thru documentation too fast ;) Thanks (again) Pascal